# You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFileById

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, custom-function

I have a Spreadsheet and Apps Script in the background that is serving a function `CONFIRM(cell)`. This function performs several actions in the background

Code that is causing trouble:

```js
function convertPDF(docId){
  const targetDir = "Redacted";
  var sourceFile = DriveApp.getFileById(docId);
  let blob = sourceFile.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');
  let docPDF = targetDir.createFile(blob);
  let fileName = templateFile.getName().replace(".", "");
  docPDF.setName(fileName + ".pdf");
  let filePDF = docPDF.getId();
  let mailContent = "Redacted
    to: user,
    subject: "Redacted "+diplomaId,
    htmlBody: mailContent,
    attachments: filePDF,
  })
  return "SENT";
}
```

THe problem is that I am getting an error:

> Exception: You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFileById. Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive) (line 24).

Line 24:

```js
var sourceFile = DriveApp.getFileById(docId);
```

I completely do not know what's the issue here. Script works fine when ran with data provided in the script, but when ran as a function, it does not work.

Comment: Are you attempting to run the function as ["Custom Function"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#advanced)

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 4):

Custom functions cannot use APIs that require authentication. All methods in the `DriveApp` class require authentication, and will thus not work. You will need to run your code through a [custom menu item](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus), a [button](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets) or an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).